# Registering user accounts in mysql with php5

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to register a user with a MySQL database. I have narrowed the problem down to this block of code.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Users`(`User`, `Pass`, `Email`, `RegKey`, `KeyList`, `ID`, `UserType`) VALUES ([".$user."],[".$pass."],[".$email."],[".$regkey."],[''],[". $NumUsers + 1 ."],['Default'])";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result != false){
        //Successfully created the user
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        $query = "UPDATE Keys SET Paid=1
        WHERE Key='".$regkey."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        header('Location: '.$website.'register.php?success');
} else{
    //Failed to create the user
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    header('Location: '.$website.'register.php?e3');
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my PHP? I have looked up everything and I think it has something to do with the result of the query but I am not sure.

UPDATE:

I Edited the query and  I believe it follows the mysql syntax, but i am still getting an error

Updated $query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users(User, Pass, Email, RegKey, KeyList, ID, UserType) VALUES ('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."','".$regkey."','',". $NumUsers + 1 .",'Default')";
```

UPDATE 2:

Fixed the Sql Query but I am still getting the same issue...

Fixed Query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Users`(`User`, `Pass`, `Email`, `RegKey`, `KeyList`, `UserType`) VALUES ('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."','".$regkey."','','Default')";
```

Comment: So, what is the actual problem here?

Comment: Use prepared statements for correct formatting on your queries

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement is wrong. If you are not parameterizing the value, the values whose data type is string (including dates) must be wrapped with single quotes, not with brackets. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(strCol, dateCol, intCol) 
VALUES ('string value', '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 0)
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(s) of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is prone to SQL injection. But I think the problem here is that you are trying to insert `ID`. Now if the `ID` is `auto_increment` therefore you don't need to insert or include that in your query.

**Another thing, the query itself is incorrect.** Since this is in PHP5, you should use PDO or MySQLi.

try this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Users`(`User`, `Pass`, `Email`, `RegKey`, `KeyList`, `UserType`) VALUES ('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."','".$regkey."','','Default')";
```